# Вывод данных из массива

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть массив `$this->userfields['fields']`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из него хочу вывести данные `name, last_name , phone` й тд,

Пробовал таким образом

```
    echo $this->userfields['fields']['last_name]']['value'];
    echo $this->userfields->fields->last_name->value;
    echo $this->userfields['fields']->last_name->value;
```

Ничего не выводит, как вывести данные ?

Comment: Ошмбки какие? `['last_name]']` - у вас нет в массиве ключей `last_name]`

Comment: @rjhdby Я даже не заметил, )Спасибо !

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($this->userfields['fields'] as $field) {
    if (!empty($field['value'])) {
        $field['name']
    }
}
```

Непонятно описан вопрос

Comment: Я обновил вопрос, убрал цикл , может так будет проще. Посмотрите пожалуйста.